# Using backhandler to disable hardwareback press and exit from specific screen but unable to do in proper way in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

here I have pasted the code of the class component. I am using backhander to disable the back button from the android platform but the issue is I am just using this code only in one screen but it affecting to the all-screen like if I try to back from the particular screen it also disable the back button I just want to disable back press and exit from the particular screen if we press back.

```
 class PinAuthentication extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleBackButton = this.handleBackButton.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          passcode: ["", "", "", ""],
          pin: "",
          confirmThePin: false,
          reconfirmPin: "",
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
      }
    
      componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
        console.log("yupp unmounted");
      }
    
      handleBackButton() {
        // Toast.show("Back button is pressed", Toast.SHORT);
        return Backhandler.exitApp();
  }
}
```

have I have added the whole code as per the comment

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  BackHandler,
} from "react-native";
import AppStore from "../../stores/AppStore";
import Theme from "../../utils/Theme";
import { Observer } from "mobx-react";
import Iconpack from "../../utils/Iconpack";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
import { UniversalNavigationHeader } from "../../components/common/NavigationHeader";
import { Screen } from "../../components/common/Screen";
import PinAuthenticationStore from "../../stores/PinAuthenticationStore";
import Toast from "react-native-simple-toast";
import { handleScreenNavigation } from "../../utils/NavigationService";
import Scanstore from "../../stores/Scanstore";

const hRem = AppStore.screenHeight / 812;
const wRem = AppStore.screenWidth / 375;

class PinAuthentication extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleBackButton = this.handleBackButton.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      passcode: ["", "", "", ""],
      pin: "",
      confirmThePin: false,
      reconfirmPin: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
    console.log("yupp unmounted");
  }

  handleBackButton() {
    // Toast.show("Back button is pressed", Toast.SHORT);
    // this.props.navigation.navigate("OtpScreen");
    return true;
  }

  showToast = () => {
    // ToastAndroid.show("Pick Enter Valid Pin !", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    Toast.show("Please Enter Valid Pin !", Toast.LONG);
  };

  onPressNumber = (num) => {
    let tempCode = this.state.passcode;
    for (var i = 0; i < tempCode.length; i++) {
      if (tempCode[i] == "") {
        tempCode[i] = num;
        if (this.state.confirmThePin) {
          this.setState({ reconfirmPin: this.state.reconfirmPin + num });
        } else {
          this.setState({ pin: this.state.pin + num });
        }
        break;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    this.setState({ passcode: tempCode });
  };

  onPressCancel = () => {
    let tempCode = this.state.passcode;
    for (var i = tempCode.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (tempCode[i] != "") {
        tempCode[i] = "";
        this.setState({
          pin: this.state.pin.slice(0, i),
          reconfirmPin: this.state.reconfirmPin.slice(0, i),
        });
        break;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    // if(tempCode.length==0){
    console.log("cancel", tempCode);
    // }
    this.setState({ passcode: tempCode });
  };

  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      passcode: ["", "", "", ""],
      confirmThePin: false,
      reconfirmPin: "",
      pin: "",
    });
  };

  confirmPin = () => {
    if (AppStore.idExist && !PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin) {
      if (this.state.pin == AppStore.userPin) {
        console.log(AppStore.secretKeyAdded, "((((((((((((((");
        if (AppStore.secretKeyAdded) {
          handleScreenNavigation("OtpScreen", {});
          Scanstore.fetchSecretKeyArray();
        } else {
          handleScreenNavigation("MainAdd", {});
        }
        this.reset();
      } else {
        this.showToast();
        this.setState({ passcode: ["", "", "", ""], pin: "" });
      }
    } else if (this.state.pin == this.state.reconfirmPin) {
      // console.log("new user");
      if (PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin) {
        PinAuthenticationStore.resetPinForUser(this.state.reconfirmPin);
        PinAuthenticationStore.setStringIsLoggedIn("true");
        PinAuthenticationStore.enableResetPin(false);
        this.reset();
        Toast.show("Pin Reset Successfully !", Toast.LONG);

        this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings");
      } else {
        PinAuthenticationStore.setPinForNewUser(this.state.reconfirmPin);
        PinAuthenticationStore.setStringIsLoggedIn("true");
        this.reset();
        this.props.navigation.navigate("MainAdd");
      }
      // PinAuthenticationStore.setUserPin(this.state.reconfirmPin)
    } else if (
      this.state.pin != this.state.reconfirmPin &&
      this.state.reconfirmPin.length > 0
    ) {
      this.setState({
        passcode: ["", "", "", ""],
        confirmThePin: false,
        reconfirmPin: "",
        pin: "",
      });
      this.showToast();
    } else {
      if (this.state.pin.length == 4 && !this.state.confirmThePin) {
        this.setState({ passcode: ["", "", "", ""], confirmThePin: true });
      } else if (this.state.reconfirmPin.length == 4) {
        this.setState({ passcode: ["", "", "", ""] });
      }
    }

    console.log("confirm pin", this.state.pin, AppStore.userPin);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(
      "---this.props.navigation.state.params.resetPin  ",
      PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin
    );
    let numbers = [
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 4 },
      { id: 5 },
      { id: 6 },
      { id: 7 },
      { id: 8 },
      { id: 9 },
      {
        id: 10,
      },
      { id: 0 },
      {
        id: 11,
      },
    ];
    return (
      <Observer>
        {() => (
          <>
            <Screen
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              statusBar={"light-content"}
              variant={true}
              showMenu={false}
              onNavigate={this.props.navigation}
            >
              <FastImage
                style={styles.container}
                source={Iconpack.PIN_SCREEN_BG}
                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
              />
              <UniversalNavigationHeader
                // hideBack={!this.state.confirmThePin ? true :(AppStore.idExist && !PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin) ? true : false}
                title={
                  !PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin && AppStore.idExist
                    ? "Enter your PIN"
                    : "Set new PIN"
                }
                goBack={
                  this.state.confirmThePin
                    ? this.reset
                    : this.props.navigation.goBack
                }
                typeTwo={
                  (this.state.confirmThePin ||
                    PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin) &&
                  true
                }
                typeOne={!PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin && true}
                styleCheck={true}
              />
              {/* </View> */}
              <View></View>
              <View></View>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.pinConfirmationText}>
                  {AppStore.idExist && !PinAuthenticationStore.resetPin
                    ? `Enter current PIN`
                    : this.state.confirmThePin
                    ? `Re-confirm PIN`
                    : `Enter new PIN`}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.codeContainer}>
                {this.state.passcode.map((p, i) => {
                  console.log("xxxx", p);
                  let style = p != "" ? styles.inputBox1 : styles.inputBox;
                  let passMask = p != "" ? "*" : "";
                  return (
                    <View style={style} key={i}>
                      <Text style={styles.inputText}>{passMask}</Text>
                    </View>
                  );
                })}
              </View>

              <View style={styles.mod0}>
                <View style={styles.numberContainer}>
                  {numbers.map((num, numb) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        {num.id == 10 ? (
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            key={num.id.toString()}
                            onPress={() => this.onPressCancel()}
                            style={
                              AppStore.isiOS ? styles.number : styles.number2
                            }
                          >
                            <Image
                              style={styles.img}
                              source={Iconpack.PIN_CANCEL}
                            />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        ) : num.id == 11 ? (
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            key={num.id.toString()}
                            onPress={() => {
                              this.confirmPin();
                            }}
                            style={
                              AppStore.isiOS ? styles.number : styles.number2
                            }
                          >
                            <Image
                              style={styles.img}
                              source={Iconpack.PIN_CHECK}
                            />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        ) : (
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            key={num.id.toString()}
                            onPress={() =>
                              this.onPressNumber(num.id.toString())
                            }
                            style={
                              AppStore.isiOS ? styles.number : styles.number2
                            }
                          >
                            <Text style={styles.numberText}>
                              {num.id.toString()}
                            </Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
            </Screen>
          </>
        )}
      </Observer>
    );
  }
}

export default PinAuthentication;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mod0: { alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#021831",
  },
  headerStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: hRem * 56,
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 24,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backButton: {
    width: wRem * 12,
    height: hRem * 21,
  },
  pinText: {
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginLeft: wRem * 101,
    fontSize: hRem * 18,
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed1,
    lineHeight: hRem * 16,
    flex: 1,
  },
  pinConfirmationText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: hRem * 44,
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed3,
    lineHeight: hRem * 19.07,
  },
  borderStyleBase: {
    width: 30,
    height: 45,
  },

  borderStyleHighLighted: {
    borderColor: "#707070",
  },

  underlineStyleBase: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    height: 45,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },

  underlineStyleHighLighted: {
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
  },
  number: {
    borderRadius:
      Math.round(
        Dimensions.get("window").width + Dimensions.get("window").height
      ) / 2,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.2,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.2,
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 12,
    marginVertical: hRem * 9,
  },
  number2: {
    borderRadius:
      Math.round(
        Dimensions.get("window").width + Dimensions.get("window").height
      ) / 2,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.2,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.2,
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 12,
    marginVertical: hRem * 9,
    shadowColor: "rgba(27, 100, 206, 0.8)",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 5,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,

    elevation: 10,
  },
  numberContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    marginTop: hRem * 99,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    shadowColor: Theme.shadow_Button,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,

    elevation: 3,
  },

  numberText: {
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed4,
    // lineHeight: hRem * 16,
    // position: "absolute",
    textAlign: "center",
    color: Theme.white_color,
  },
  codeContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 49,
    marginTop: hRem * 50,
  },
  inputBox: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#707070",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    // backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  inputBox1: {
    width: wRem * 62,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    // backgroundColor: "green",
  },
  inputText: {
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed3,
    marginBottom: hRem * 21,
  },
  img: {
    width: wRem * 30,
    height: hRem * 22,
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you include all relevant code? Where, and when, is this `PinAuthentication` component mounted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: do you need whole file code? @DrewReese

Comment: Maybe. My guess is that this component remains mounted when you don't want it to, so what is rendering it? We can start from there.

Comment: here i have added the whole code pls look into it@DrewReese

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't think we need to see the entirety of this `PinAuthentication` component, but rather the parent component of `PinAuthentication` so we can see where and under what conditions `PinAuthentication` is rendered.

Comment: there is no any parent component of pinauthetication component but there is one thing if pinauthetication is assigned to initial route name in routes then is the cause of this problem?@DrewReese

Comment: Possibly, can you include that code then?